# An English proverb for we should always use sweet words

Tags: meaning-in-context, proverbs

Aisi vaani boliye, man ka apa khoye
Auran ka shital kare, aphaun shital hoye

English translation:

Speak such words, sans ego’s ploy
Body remains composed, giving the listener joy

Written by [Kabir Das](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabir)

I want an English proverb for we should speak such words which are pleasing to the listener’s mind or no one feels bad. Such an expression not only gives pleasure to the listeners, but along with it one’s own mind also experiences happiness. With the use of such a sweet and melodious speech, we can make any person feel love and respect towards him. Therefore, melodious voice should always be used.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if these are exactly the same, but the closest ones I can think of are

**You’ll catch more flies with honey than vinegar**
(Metaphorically means that you are more likely to persuade people by being nice to them than by being forceful)

and

**If you don’t have something nice to say, don’t say anything at all**
(Literal)

Answer (score 0):

There's a biblical proverb Prov 16:24

> Gracious words are a honeycomb, sweet to the soul and healing to the bones.

It's not well known (and technically is a Hebrew proverb translated to English)